# How to make a correct Visits table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I'm working in mini webpage creator, the users can create a page and that page has some buttons. I need to count the visits for page and clicks in every button.

I'm thinking in create two tables, page_visits and buttons_clicks.

**page_visits**

- id
- page_id
- operating_system
- browser
- ip
- country

**buttons_clicks**

- id
- button_id
- operating_system
- browser
- ip
- country

I can have 10 000 pages and every page can get 2000 visits per day, 20 000 000 records in a day.

I need to show to user analytics for their pages, for example visits by browsers, filter by dates, etc.

Which is the best way to store that? I'm working with MySQL and Laravel livewire.

Comment: Why use DB for that? Any specific reason?  Google Analytics can be integrated with Laravel...

Comment: I didn't know you could use google analytics to track user clicks on every button and every page. Could you give info?

Comment: https://codelapan.com/post/google-analytics-laravel found this on Google